# How to inherit variable from method in another class in Python

Tags: python, oop

Basically, I have a program that makes two separate frames. When the user clicks "Logga in", I want to save the entries the user made, and use them in the class for the other frame. However, I do not understand how I inherit these.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as msgbox

class emailCore(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title("Email Prime")
        self.geometry("800x480")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.config(bg="white")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.windowFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.windowFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.windowFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.windowFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        frame = StartPage(self.windowFrame, self)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

class StartPage(tk.Frame, emailCore):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.emaildict = {"GMail":"Smtp.gmail.com", "Yahoo":"Mail.yahoo.com", "Outlook":"Smtp.live.com"}

        self.emailstring = tk.StringVar()
        self.emailstring.set("GMail")
        self.email = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.emailstring, "GMail", "Yahoo", "Outlook")
        self.email.grid(column=1, row=1)

        accLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Emailaddress")
        accLabel.grid(column=1, row=2, pady=5)

        pwLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Lösenord")
        pwLabel.grid(column=1, row=3)

        self.accEntry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.accEntry.grid(column=2, row=2, ipadx=15, ipady=3)

        self.pwEntry = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        self.pwEntry.grid(column=2, row=3, ipadx=15, ipady=3)

        self.loginButton = tk.Button(self, text="Logga in", command=self.sendpagemail)
        self.loginButton.grid(column=1, row=4, pady=5)

    def sendpagemail(self):
        self.acctest = str(self.accEntry.get())
        self.pwtest = str(self.pwEntry.get())
        self.emailtest = str(self.emailstring.get())

        frame = SendPage(s.windowFrame, self)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

class SendPage(StartPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        print(StartPage.acctest) # Here is where I want to print the variable I created in the method sendmailpage inside the class StartPage

        ToLabel = tk.Label(self, text="To: ")
        ToLabel.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="w")
        self.ToEntry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.ToEntry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="w", ipadx=15, ipady=3)

        SubjectLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Subject:")
        SubjectLabel.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="w")
        self.SubjectEntry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.SubjectEntry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky="w", ipadx=15, ipady=3)

        TextBoxLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Mail: ")
        TextBoxLabel.grid(column=1, row=3)
        self.TextBoxEntry = tk.Text(self)
        self.TextBoxEntry.grid(column=2, row=3)

        sendButton = tk.Button(self, text="Skicka")
        sendButton.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky="w")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = emailCore()
    s.mainloop()
```

Basically, I want the line `print(StartPage.acctest)` to access whatever acctest was assigned to in the first class.

Comment: Don't store your data as attributes of objects that are supposed to represent GUIs. Instead store it in some common place that all the GUIs can reach. Maybe all the GUI objects would have an attribute `.data`, then  `x.data` is a reference to the same dictionary instance for all GUI-instances `x`, and that dictionary contains the master copy of the data.  (Or, go the whole hog, and read up on Model-View-Controller design patterns:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute this line:

```
frame = SendPage(s.windowFrame, self)
```

you are calling the function `SendPage.__init__`, which is declared like this:

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
```

So the object that was named "s.windowFrame" in the call is named "parent" in the function. and the object that was named "self" in the call is named "controller" in the function.  They are the same objects by different names.

A variable named by "self.acctest" in the call will be named by "controller.acctest" in the function.  That's because "self" in the call is named "controller" in the function.  It's basic to how Python works.  They're the same object, so you can access the object's variables with the "." notation.

Change your print statement to:

```
print(controller.acctest)
```

I see some other problems with your program but this should allow you to move forward.